# What case after "с"?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

I read the phrase *начать с дерева* in the context of a young man wanting to change his life and deciding to start by planting a tree.
Why is дерева in the genitive case, while I would have expected the instrumental?
A grammar book of mine indeed indicates that *с* can be followed by a genitive or an instrumental, but is there a rule telling which to choose?
Or should I just learn for each possible combination verb+*с* what the correct case is?

Comment: *Or should I just learn for each possible combination verb+с what the correct case is?* < this.

Comment: Phrases involving с + genitive that are useful: (1) с этой точки зрения ("from this point of view"), (2) с одной стороны ... с другой стороны ("on the one hand... on the other hand," or literally "from one hand... from the other hand"), (3) начиная с девятнадцатого века ("starting in the 19th century", or literally "starting from the 19th century").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With instrumental, **с** means "with". With genitive, **с** means "from" or "off" — that is, moving away from a thing's surface (as opposed to **из** which is for moving away from inside a thing). You take a thing "off" a shelf (**с полки**) but "from" a cupboard (**из шкафа**). For all intents and purposes, this **с** is a different preposition than the one meaning "with".

Among the more abstract meanings of **с**+genitive, the most common one is "beginning with", "from X onwards", or "since" when talking about time. Now of course, with prepositions used abstractly it's not always easy to figure out the underlying metaphor; **начать с дерева** is, literally, to "start *from* a tree" rather than *with* a tree, whereas in English one more commonly begins/starts "with" things. There's no particular reason why it's one or the other (or something else entirely); so I suppose with some verbs, you just have to learn it.

Still, you might want to first try and see if you can follow the logic behind which **с** it is; there are many cases where, abstract or not, that logic is plain enough, e.g. in **взыскать с должника**, it's clear that the debt is collected "from" someone rather than "with" them — whereas in **расплатиться с кредитором**, it makes mor sense to say that a debt are settled "with" a lender rather than "from" them.

Comment: Thank you for your (as usual) crystal-clear comment, dear Nikolay. I am really amazed by your linguistic and didactical talent. May I take the liberty to ask what your mother tongue is? [ I'm curious because usually people are not so good at explaining the whys and wherefores of their native language since everything seems so natural to them :-)]

Comment: While we are at it, could you please also explain when *от* is used for translating *from* ?

Comment: Glad to hear that :) My mother tongue is Russian; my mother, however, was a translator from Czech and Polish, so already the lullabies and nursery rhymes I grew up with were in several different, but not completely different, languages — and that I suppose was where it all began.

Comment: **От** is for either leaving the vicinity of a thing, or becoming a breakaway part of it. Prepositions of to/from motion can be rather neatly arranged in pairs: **из** is the inverse of **в** (the accusative one, "into"), **с** (+genitive) is the inverse of **на** (+accusative), and  **от** is the inverse of **к**. A letter from someone is **письмо от** — but note that a letter from *someplace* is **письмо из** (or, occasionally, **письмо с**).

Comment: Thanks again for your supplementary  explanations, Nikolay (and the fragment of your autobiography!).

Comment: You say с + genitive for movement means "away from a surface." I had learned that this is the meaning of от + genitive, for instance the movement of a rocket is от земли, not с земли. How does this fit your explanation of the distinction between с and от?

Comment: @KCd I can only think of one case when you'd say **от земли** about a rocket; it's with the verb **оторваться**. For all others, such as **подняться** or **запустить**, it's definitely **с**. Are you sure you're not mixing them up?

Comment: Now that I think more closely, I was imagining not movement but location, e.g., рассотяние ракета от земли.

Answer (score 2):

> начать с дерева = start from a/the tree
>
> начать с деревом = start having a/the tree

Answer (score 2):

- **с** + *instr.* = "with"
- **с** + *gen.* = "from" (more or less, for some meanings of "from")

Others have already given more precise answers about the above, so I will just mention the fairly rare

**с** + *acc.*

which is used in sentences like

размером с морскую свинку = about the size of a guinea pig

размером с тыкву = roughly as big as a pumpkin

Answer (score 0):

*С* can be followed by genitive, accusative or instrumental, but it's not the preposition which governs the case of a complement, it's the verb or noun it completes.

*Начать с + gen.* literally means "start from (the top of) the tree", the preposition *c* here being used in the sense "from the top of", as opposed to *из* "from the inside of" and *от* "from the proximity of".

This verb governs *с + gen.* in the same way *жить*, *брать* and even *смеяться* and *бить* in some dialects do: *брать с него долг, жить с нетрудовых доходов, **смеяться с клоуна, **бить с локтя*. It's just how these verbs work.

The last two examples are dialectal and sound quite peculiar to those not used to them, but totally OK to those who are.